# How to compile a .jar without errors concerning libraries?

Tags: java

I decompile a .jar with JD-GUI to edit a file with an error. The problem is that when I open the Eclipse project to recompile the same classes, it has a lot of errors concerning libraries. Therefore, compiling the .jar again to use it in another project, doesn't work.

Shouldn't those libraries be in the original .jar? How does the original .jar work without those libraries? How can I fix it without having to find and add all the libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Java compiler doesn't include external libraries in your jar. You should use build tools like Maven or Gradle to deal with it.
Or place all jar with dependencies in /lib dir next to your jar and add this dir to classpath in jar's manifest file

Comment: But this jar worked by itself before. How can it do it without those libraries?

Answer (score 0):

During compilation you need all the referenced classes in your class path for the class to compile. You need to get all those jars and put into classpath for compilation to work.

If you have a fat jar which includes all the required classes then you would not need any other jar.